# ¿Como devolver una lista de objetos en una API REST Java?

Tags: java, webservice, api, rest

Tengo un servicio rest que devuelve una lista de objetos de productos, el cual puede devolver uno o más productos dependiendo de lo que se consulte. El problema que tengo es que cuando devuelvo la lista con un solo objeto, devuelve el json como el objeto en sí y no como una lista:

```
{  
   "lista": {
       "codigo": "8239",
       "descripcion": "DESCRIPCION",
       "existe": "true"   
    }
}
```

Pero cuando se consultan varios productos, el servicio si devuelve la lista, que es lo que necesito que haga siempre:

```
{
    "lista": [
        {
            "codigo": "7742",
            "descripcion": "DESCRIPCION",
            "existe": "true"
        },
        {
            "codigo": "8239",
            "descripcion": "DESCRIPCION",
            "existe": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Es decir, necesito que siempre retorne el json de la siguiente manera cuando la lista contiene un solo objeto:

```
{  
   "lista": [
       {
           "codigo": "8239",
           "descripcion": "DESCRIPCION",
           "existe": "true"   
       }
    ]
}
```

Este es el código del método que devuelve esta información:

```
@GET
@Path("ejemplo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Object> obtenerLista() throws Exception {
    List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Object object = new Object();
    lista.add(producto);

    return lista;
}
```

Esto es básicamene lo que hace el servicio, tiene una lista de objetos, y dependiendo de ciertas condiciones, se llena la lista con uno o más objetos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe crear dos objetos uno Lista y otro Producto,

Clase Producto

```
public class Producto{
  private Integer codigo;
  private String descripcion;
  private Boolean existe;

  public Producto(){}
  public Producto(Integer codigo, String descripcion, Boolean existe){
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.existe = existe;
  }

  ...//métodos get y set por cada atributo

}
```

Clase Lista

```
public class Lista{
  private List<Producto> productos;

  public Lista(){}

  ... //Método get y set para productos

}
```

Debe cambiar su método por

```
@GET
@Path("ejemplo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response obtenerLista() throws Exception {
  List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList();
  Producto producto = new Producto(123, "un producto", Boolean.TRUE ); 
  productos.add(producto);

  Lista lista = new Lista();
  lista.setProductos(productos);

  return Response.status(200).entity(lista).build();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no tengo 50 de reputación y no puedo comentar al usuario de arriba, estaría bien que te pases por https://github.com/google/gson 
Es muy sencillo de utilizar y encontrarás mucha documentación online.

Por aquí te dejo un link a lo que pides utilizando la librería **gson**.
https://www.baeldung.com/gson-list

Un saludo, espero que te ayude ;)